# Submit form to same page in custom module

Tags: module, custom

I'm looking to submit my form to the same page, but it just redirects to the admin dashboard.

Here's my .phtml file:

```
<?php 
    $action = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    if(isset($_POST['email_address'])){
        $email = $_POST['email_address'];
        echo $email;
    }
?>
<p>Please enteer the customers email address and press reset. You will be given the customers new password after.</p>
<form name="reset_password" method="POST" id="reset-password" autocomplete="off" action="<?php echo $block->getPostUrl(); ?>">
    <div class="admin__form-field-control">
        <input type="email" name="email_address" placeholder="Enter email here..." class="admin__control-text" action"<?php echo $action; ?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="admin__footer-main-actions">
        <input type="submit"  class="action-secondary" value="Reset" />
    </div>
</form>
```

How do I make the form submit to the same page without it redirecting? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have not added your block class here so please use below code and update your class . At admin end we need a form key to submit any form .

```
<?php 

use \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class BlockClass extends Template
{
    public $formKey;


    public function __construct(
        Context $context,

    ) {

        $this->formKey = $context->getFormKey();
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function getFormKey()
    {
        return $this->formKey->getFormKey();
    }
    public function getPostUrl()
   {
     //what ever your code that you have already
   }
}
```

and change your .phtml file to something like this

```
<?php 
    $action = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    if(isset($_POST['email_address'])){
        $email = $_POST['email_address'];
        echo $email;
    }
?>
<p>Please enteer the customers email address and press reset. You will be given the customers new password after.</p>
<form name="reset_password" method="POST" id="reset-password" autocomplete="off">

  <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php /* @noEscape */ echo $block->getFormKey()?>" />
    <div class="admin__form-field-control">
        <input type="email" name="email_address" placeholder="Enter email here..." class="admin__control-text" action"<?php echo $action; ?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="admin__footer-main-actions">
        <input type="submit"  class="action-secondary" value="Reset" />
    </div>
</form>
```

We have added a hidden field that with name "form_key" .

Hope this helps .